# Vim with Powershell

Tags: vim, powershell

I'm using gvim on Windows.

In my _vimrc I've added:

```
set shell=powershell.exe
set shellcmdflag=-c
set shellpipe=>
set shellredir=>

function! Test()
  echo system("dir -name")
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 Test :call Test()
```

If I execute this function (:Test) I see nonsense characters (non number/letter ASCII characters).

If I use cmd as the shell, it works (without the -name), so the problem seems to be with getting output from powershell into vim.

Interestingly, this works great:

```
:!dir -name
```

As does this:

```
:r !dir -name
```

**UPDATE:**  confirming behavior mentioned by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94382/vim-with-powershell#101743)

If you execute the set commands mentioned above in the _vimrc, :Test outputs nonsense.  However, if you execute them directly in vim instead of in the _vimrc, :Test works as expected.

Also, I've tried using iconv in case it was an encoding problem:

```
:echo iconv( system("dir -name"), "unicode", &enc )
```

But this didn't make any difference.  I could be using the wrong encoding types though.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: I just thought it would be so cool.  Imagine the power/flexibility!

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue? Powershell uses Unicode if it thinks the target is a file. Try -encoding ASCII as a switch to powershell.

Comment: Any idea how I can have pass that switch in through Vim?

Comment: -encoding does not seem to be a valid switch for powershell

Comment: Sorry Kevin, the encoding switch is used in conjunction with out-file which I guess is not applicable here. I'd like to help, but sadly, what you're trying works for me ;)

Comment: I might just have to install powershell to try and figure this out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a bit of a hack, but the following works in Vim 7.2. Notice, I am running Powershell within a CMD session.

```
if has("win32")
    set shell=cmd.exe
    set shellcmdflag=/c\ powershell.exe\ -NoLogo\ -NoProfile\ -NonInteractive\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned
    set shellpipe=|
    set shellredir=>
endif

function! Test()
  echo system("dir -name")
endfunction
```

Tested with the following...

- `:!dir -name`
- `:call Test()`

Answer (score 18):

I ran into a similar problem described by many here.

Specifically, calling

```
:set shell=powershell
```

manually from within vim would cause powershell to work fine, but as soon as I added:

```
set shell=powershell
```

to my vimrc file I would get the error "Unable to open temp file .... "

The problem is that by default when shell is modified, vim automatically sets shellxquote to " which means that shell commands will look like the following:

```
 powershell -c "cmd > tmpfile"
```

Where as this command needs to look like this, in order for vim to read the temp file:

```
 powershell -c "cmd" > tmpfile
```

Setting shellquote to " in my vimrc file and unsetting shellxquote (i.e. setting it to a blank space) seem to fix all my problems:

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-c
set shellquote=\"
set shellxquote=
```

I've also tried taking this further and scripting vim a bit using the system() call:
[system() with powershell in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605917/system-with-powershell-in-vim)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the problem is that Powershell uses the native String encoding for .NET, which is UTF-16 plus a byte-order-mark.

When it's piping objects between commands it's not a problem. It's a total PITA for external programs though.

You can pipe the output through out-file, which does support changing the encoding, but still formats the output for the terminal that it's in by default (arrgh!), so things like "Get-Process" will truncate with ellipses, etc. You can specify the width of the virtual terminal that Out-File uses though.

Not sure how useful this information is, but it does illuminate the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
"dir \*vim\*"
```

with

```
 " -command { dir \*vim\* }"
```

**EDIT:** Try using cmd.exe as the shell and put "powershell.exe" before "-command"

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question - here is something else to add to the confusion. Without making any changes to my .vimrc file, if I then run the following commands in gvim:

```
:set shell=powershell.exe
:set shellcmdflag=-noprofile
:echo system("dir -name")
```

It behaves as expected!

If I make the same changes to my .vimrc file, though (the shell and shellcmdflag options), running :echo system("dir -name") returns the nonsense characters!

Answer (score 2):

The initial example code works fine for me when I plop it in vimrc.

So now I'm trying to figure out what in my vimrc is making it function. Possibly:

```
set encoding=utf8
```

**Edit**: Yep, that appears to do it. You probably want to have VIM defaulting to unicode anyway, these days...

Answer (score 1):

Try instead

`set shellcmdflag=\ -c`

---

Explanation:

Vim uses tempname() to generate a temp file path that system() reads.

If &shell contains 'sh' and &shellcmdflag starts with '-' 
then tempname() generates a temp file path with forward slashes.

Thus, if

`set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-c`

then Vim will try to read a temp file with forward slashes that 
cannot be found.

A remedy is to set instead

`set shellcmdflag=\ -c`

that is, add a whitespace to &shellcmdflag so that the first character
is no longer '-' and tempname() produces a temp file path with backward 
slashes that can be found by system().

---

I remarked on the vim_dev mailing list ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/vTR05EZyfE0 ) that this deserves better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers on this page were working for me until I found this hint from https://github.com/dougireton/mirror_pond/blob/master/vimrc - set shellxquote= [space character] was the missing piece.

```
if has("win32") || has("gui_win32") 
     if executable("PowerShell") 
        " Set PowerShell as the shell for running external ! commands 
        " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605917/system-with-powershell-in-vim      
        set shell=PowerShell 
        set shellcmdflag=-ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned\ -Command 
        set shellquote=\" 
        " shellxquote must be a literal space character. 
        set shellxquote=  
   endif 
endif
```

Comment: What does "work" mean here?  Can you select lines and `!sort-object` them (replacing the lines with the sorted lines)?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers in this and the related thread, add the following to your `$profile` assuming you installed `diffutils` from chocolatey:

```bsh
Remove-Item Alias:diff -force
```

And add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if (has('win32') || has('gui_win32')) && executable('pwsh')
    set shell=pwsh
    set shellcmdflag=\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned\ -NoProfile\ -Nologo\ -NonInteractive\ -Command
endif
```

**make sure `shellcmdflag` is exactly as shown**

All credit for these solutions to their respective contributors, this is merely an aggregation post.

Comment: My system only supports the command 'powershell', not 'pwsh'. Presumably, by quick Google search, this is because 'pwsh' is supported in v6+. The version I have is 5.1.19041.906.  I checked this with the command 'Get-Host | Select-Object Version'. I still upvoted because I just replaced all instances of 'pwsh' in the above with 'powershell' and it seemed to work.

Comment: There is a difference between Windows PowerShell, which comes with Windows, and PowerShell Core which you install separately, e.g.: choco install -y powershell-core

Answer (score 0):

I propose an hackish solution. It doesn't really solve the problem, but it get the job done somehow.

This [Vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2837) automate the creation of a temporary script file, powershell call through cmd.exe and paste of the result. It's not as nice as a proper powershell handling by vim, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

[actf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205836/actf) answer works for me, but because of Powershell built in DIFF (which is different from the Linux one) you must add this line to your Powershell profile to have diff working again in VIM:

```
Remove-Item Alias:diff -force
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running GVim v8.2 (Windows).

Using the fullpath to the executable works for me:

```
set shell=C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't use VIM but Powershell's default output is Unicode.  Notepad can read unicode, you could use it to see if you are getting the output you expect.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, and doesn't actually address the issue. Vim works fine with Unicode.