# How to filter lines from vim with powershell

Tags: powershell, vim

I have the following file:

```
firstname,lastname,email
jane,doe,jane@example.com
drew,neil,drew@vimcasts.org
john,smith,john@example.com
```

I execute `1,$!sort -property @{"Expression"={$_.split(',')[1]}}`

It outputs the following error:

```
At line:1 char:49
+ sort -property @{Expression={$_.split(',')[1]}} <C:/Users/wild/AppData/Local/Tem ...
+                                                 ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

In my `_vmrc`:

```
set shell=powershell\ -ExecutionPolicy\ Unrestricted\ -NoProfile\ -NoLogo\ -NonInteractive
set shellcmdflag=-command
set shellpipe=|
set shellredir=>
```

Also I've tried with no result from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94382/vim-with-powershell):

```
if has("win32")
     set shell=cmd.exe
     if has("gui_running")
     set shellcmdflag=/c\ chcp\ 65001\ &&\ powershell.exe\ -NoLogo\ -NoProfile\ -NonInteractive\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned
     else
     set shellcmdflag=/c\ powershell.exe\ -NoLogo\ -NoProfile\ -NonInteractive\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned
     endif
     set shellpipe=|
     set shellredir=>
endif
```

How to use `Sort-Object` cmdlet with vim?

Comment: You should probably start by saying what you have and what you want so we can understand the need for `vim` at all. The executed-command at the top makes no sense

Comment: I don't have specific task to solve right now. I want to understand how can I use vim+powershell together. The ability to filter lines through external program looks interesting. It is disappointing that it does not work. The need for `vim` is out of scope here.

Comment: So is this still the status of things: one cannot  filter lines with PowerShell while using Vim?

Comment: It looks like it's not possible right now, @Alan. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. In theory, you should be able to use pipes instead of the input redirection operator '<' by setting **noshelltemp** in Vim, but it's not currently implemented in Windows:

> 'shelltemp' 'stmp'    boolean (Vi default off, Vim default on)
>
> global
>
> {not in Vi}
>
> When on, use temp files for shell commands.  When off
>   use a pipe.   When using a pipe is not possible temp files are used
>   anyway.   Currently a pipe is only supported on Unix.

So, it looks like we are stuck for now...

Comment: Thank you very much! You just helped me solve what I have been fighting with from time to time in the last few months! :) I have been using PowerShell Core as my default shell under Linux, which was basically perfect, apart from this issue that was hindering my experience, but no longer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Purely from PS user perspective: the issue with this approach is the fact, that PowerShell (as error message tried to explain) does not have `<` operator. It's one of few reserved but not yet implemented (probably due to relatively low demand).

Unless there is a way to force vim to use "usual" PowerShell syntax with piping elements into `Sort-Object`, you won't get far.