# External commands from Vim are not recognized, including 'ls' and 'pwd'

Tags: windows, shell, vim

I'm still learning vim and during my vimtutor session I wrote `:!ls` but it couldn't be found. I've also tried `:sh` which works fine but I can't figure out why using the bang symbol wouldn't

edit: I was wrong. ':sh' brings up the shell but ls and pwd still don't work with that instance of the shell

edit2: I've been using Powershell and realize now that `ls` and `pwd` are not commands available to cmd. I added

```
set shell=powershell.exe
set shellcmdflag=-c
set shellpipe=>
set shellredir=>
```

into _vimrc gleamed from this question: [Vim with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94382/vim-with-powershell)

Comment: `ls` is not a valid Windows command. Whereas `:sh` is a vim command that launches a terminal/command prompt.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure what you mean. Unless I'm mistaken, `:!xxx` should send a single line external command to the shell so `:!ls` should list the files in the working directory, right?

Comment: On a machine where `ls` is a valid command, yes. It isn't on Windows. Try running `ls` from a cmd.exe window and you'll see what I mean. Try `:!dir` in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the "bang" added to commands like `:w!` and the separate `:!` command, which passes the remainder to the *shell*. (Also, many built-in commands like `:ls` and `:pwd` are named by common shell commands found on Unix / Linux.)

**If you're on Windows, you simply don't have those common Linux commands like `ls` and `pwd`.** (The equivalents would be `dir` and `echo %CD%`, resp.)

If you install a Unix emulation layer like the one provided by *Cygwin* or the *GNU Win32* project, you'll get corresponding binaries (`ls.exe`) and can then invoke then (or even reconfigure Vim's `'shell'` option to use such shell).

Comment: I see, I've been using Powershell and didn't realize the regular shell doesn't have access to such commands. Is there a way to set Powershell as the shell vim uses?

Comment: in vimrc: `set shell=powershell` and `set shellcmdflag=-command`

Answer (score 1):

`:!` in vim runs the given command through the `'shell'`.

On Windows this is `cmd.exe`. `ls` is not a valid command on Windows. As such `:!ls` will not work on Windows.

`:!dir`, on the other hand, will.