# _vimrc setting not reflected for files opened in vim from powershell

Tags: powershell, vim

When I open any text file in vim in the dos prompt, the `_vimrc` settings are properly reflected into the prompt and I am happy. However, when I open the same file (or any file for that matter) from powershell, the _vimrc settings are not reflected.

I mean, Let's say I open a file `someFile.txt` in vim from dos prompt and do `:set tabstop`, it shows `tabstop=4`, which is correct since my `_vimrc` file has this entry. But, while doing the same from powershell it shows `tabstop=8`.
I've searched the internet for this and also different forums. I found no solution.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94382/vim-with-powershell), I dont think that is related to my issue, however, I still tried it but the problem is still exists.
Every time I open a file in vim in powershell, I have to set all vim config's manually that I have in my _vimrc.

My `_vimrc` settings :

[image: my _vimrc settings]

Not sure what i'm missing here. Do we have to create vim configuration separately for powershell? If the info is not sufficient, i can provide more. please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with `:echo $MYVIMRC` and `:scriptnames` to see from what files `vim` loads configuration at startup.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply @phd
`:echo $MYVIMRC` shows `U:\.vimrc` That drive is my unix home. not sure why it's picking up config from that. Is there a way I could change the vimrc for powershell.

Comment: Is it possible you're getting two different binaries of Vim from DOS Prompt vs. Powershell? Check `:version` on each of them and compare. Is your PATH different between them?

Comment: @filbranden. it's the same version for both dos and powershell.

Comment: I don't know how to get this solved. If anyone gets something like this and find a solution. please add it here. Meanwhile, I have added those configurations in the vimrc of U: drive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your default for vimrc file is different when run from Powershell, but you should be able to solve this by setting `VIMINIT` environment variable to the full path of your vimrc (path to your `_vimrc`). Make sure that your Powershell picks up this environment variable, if not you can make use of Powershell profile file (which you can lookup using `$profile` in your existing shell) to set this environment variable.